# Media query not wokring properly

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I am trying to use media query on one of my website, At the beginning it was working well, But later when I finished all media query section site design is not working properly, This are the media queries I used in `style.css`:

`@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {}`

`@media screen and (max-width: 375px) {}`

`@media screen and (max-width:1920px) {}`

`@media screen and (max-width:1440px) {}`

In `intex.html` file:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  media="all" />`

After adding all this only the last media query with `1440px` is working. What may the possible reasons for this?

Comment: ... You should use MIN-WIDTH instead... Max-width fits all resolutions UNDER the one you give. As you say, as last statement max-width 1440, then all previous media queries are not used since all statements (except 1920 one) are under 1440... !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using media queries as under, i.e. specify exactly which media queries to apply.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 375px) {}

@media screen and (min-width: 376px) and (max-width: 768px) {}

@media screen and (min-width: 769px) and (max-width:1440px) {}

@media screen and (min-width: 1441px) and (max-width:1920px) {}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use media queries in sequence like below. It will work.

```
@media screen and (max-width:1440px) {}

@media screen and (max-width:1920px) {}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {}

@media screen and (max-width: 375px) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

you might have missed closing some brackets {} for the media queries. Check whether u have closed all your media queries..